# Auto scale HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if its possible to make non-scrollable web page with full width header, content and footer to scale on different monitor sizes? So it can be run as frontend for web kiosk.

Comment: Yes. But have you taken into account how small the text will be on a smartphone screen?

Comment: I don't need it to run on smartphones. I will run chrome in --kiosk mode just for this web page. and it will be on local network so i do controll client pc's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could do something simple like ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfTD3/)):

Body:

```
<div id="header"> header </div>
body
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

And use CSS to manage the layout:

```
#header{width:100%; background:#f00;}
#footer{width:100%; background:#f00;bottom:0;position:absolute;}
```

To make the page non-scrollable, you can simply hide scrollbars on the page by specifying:

```
body{ overflow: hidden;}
```

This wont work perfectly for all scenarios, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vh and wh units on CSS 3.0

Check this [link](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/07/css-units-use-now/) for more info, also you could view some examples [here](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) and see it in [action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUiVLIDoGuc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  Here is a Javascript Function I created with a little CSS.  This is great for auto-sizing a page to fit without changing the ratio.  This will resize the page on startup and when the window is resized.

CSS:

```
body{
   height:620px;
   width:1023px;
   position:absolute;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
   -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ratio;
var left;
resize();

$(window).resize(function () {resize();});

function resize()
{
    ratio = window.innerHeight / $('body').innerHeight();
    if (window.innerWidth / $('body').innerWidth() < ratio) {
        ratio = window.innerWidth / $('body').innerWidth();
    }
    ratio -= .04;
    $('body').css('-ms-zoom', ratio);
    $('body').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
    $('body').css('-o-transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
    $('body').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
    $('body').css('transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
    left = ($(window).innerWidth() - $('body').outerWidth() * ratio) / 2;
    $('body').css('left', left);
}
```